# Return Response model as a value in JSON response

Tags: python, api, fastapi, uvicorn

I would like to make that my query returns something like that:

```
{"message": "OK",
 "data": {
      "username": "string",
      "pseudo": "string",
      "email": "string"}
}
```

But i cant make my model return inside JSON i am only capable of returning ONLY the model so it gives that :

```
{
 "username": "string",
 "pseudo": "string",
 "email": "string"
}
```

That is the code that i tried to run to get the first code snippet

```
@app.post("/", response_model=_models.UserOut, status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def postUser(userPost: _models.UserIn):
  if not userPost.regex_check_email(userPost.email):
    raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, detail=f"Email: {userPost.email} not valid format")
  if not userPost.regex_check_username(userPost.username):
    raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                        detail=f"Username: {userPost.username} not valid format")
  else:
    db_user.append(userPost)
    return {"message": "OK",
            "data": userPost}
```

and my models :

```
class UserOut(BaseModel):
  username: str
  pseudo: Optional[str] = None
  email: str


class UserIn(UserOut):
  username: str
  pseudo: Optional[str] = None
  email: str
  password: str

  def regex_check_email(self, email):
    match = re.match(email_regex, email)
    is_match_email = bool(match)
    return is_match_email

  def regex_check_username(self, username):
    match = re.match(username_regex, username)
    is_match_username = bool(match)
    return is_match_username
```

this only returns me

> pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for
> UserOut response -> username   field required
> (type=value_error.missing) response -> email   field required
> (type=value_error.missing)

It would be great if u could help me and tell me why i was failing, i think i did not understood everything about response models. Thanks.

Comment: I know i could to that "manually" by displaying each field like <"username": userPost.username> but i would like to avoid that if possible, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the header of your POST handler you are using

```py
@app.post("/", response_model=_models.UserOut ...)
...
```

So when you try to return something that doesn't match the `UserOut` model it returns an error.
Create a model that defines your message and data structure as desired and use  that as the `response_model`

Happy coding

*Edit: Have you tried using something like this:* (`python 3.10+`)

```py
class UserData(BaseModel):
  username: str
  pseudo: Optional[str] = None
  email: str

class UserOut(BaseModel):
  message: str
  data: UserData | None = None
```

When in doubt, the official documentation usually has [examples](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-nested-models/#use-the-submodel-as-a-type).

Comment: Oh thanks, i will try that. So i need to create a model that contains a field message that equals to "Ok" and a field data that returns my user fields ? if its that i understant a little more how response models works, i thought the response model impacts only on the class that we return, not the whole response

Comment: The idea is to strictly define the structure of the whole response from the endpoint. So in your instance it should contain `message: str` and `data: UserOut`  attributes.

Comment: Thanks i learned something, im quite new to APIs and OOP, i can't seem to make that data field usable, could you help me with the build of that data field? I tried creating a dict but cant seem to make it work thanks a lot !

Comment: I tried the code that you showed me, my data field contains nothing, i removed the None part, and i got this error "response -> data
  field required (type=value_error.missing)". Did i missed something ? Why my UserOut is not capable of getting the UserIn values that are the same that are in the data field ?

Comment: Can you provide me an example of how you are building the return object? Have you used something like `return UserOut(message="OK", data=userPost)` or [unwrapping a dict](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/extra-models/#unwrapping-a-dict)?.

Comment: Oh, i used to just return userPost, `return UserOut(message="OK", data=userPost)` worked perfectly. So it means i didnt really understood how all of that works, why python is not able to get the fields from userPost.username etc.. and put them into UserOut.data that have the same fields ?

Comment: FastAPI can do this, if you use the same attributes in a simple object (like `UserIn` and `UserOut` in your initial case). But now `UserOut` does not have the same properties as `UserIn` and  for various reasons *forcing* those fields into child objects is not implemented. The idea of `response_model` is to strictly define the structure your endpoint will return so that validation, documentation, etc. are already covered. Basically you have to describe the resource (class) your function will return and that is what we did by using a new class with the `message` and `data` property.